# Python cv2.imread returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to read my pictures with cv2.imread from a folder named "Bilder", but I always get None returned. When I put my pictures in the folder "Straßenverkehr Projekt" (the folder, where my code [module.py] is also saved) it works.

Folder path of the pictures : `C:\Users\ramif\Desktop\Straßenverkehr Projekt\Bilder`

Folder path of the code: `C:/Users/ramif/Desktop/Straßenverkehr Projekt/module.py`

Traceback (most recent call):

> File "c:/Users/ramif/Desktop/Straßenverkehr Projekt/module.py", line
>   12, in read_image   print(img.shape)
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

def read_image():
    'reading the images'
    folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"Bilder")
    for i in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(i)
        print(img.shape)

read_image()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the annoying features of cv2.imread is that it will not raise an exception if there is an error. You have to check the return value. 'NoneType' is always a clue that it couldn't find the file. There are a number of ways to solve this. Starting with your code the easiest thing I can think of is to use `os.chdir` to change the working directory to where the pictures are:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

def read_image():
    'reading the images'
    folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"Bilder")
    os.chdir(folder)
    for i in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(i)
        print(img.shape)

read_image()
```

An alternative solution is to use `os.path.join` inside your for loop, i.e.

```
for i in os.listdir(folder):
    fullpath = os.path.join(folder, i)
    img = cv2.imread(fullpath)
    print(img.shape)
```

The @gautam-bose answer should work for Linux systems, but I forget what Python wants path separators to look like in Windows. If you `print(folder)` you can get an idea of what the separators are.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that os.listdir is giving you just the file names inside of the Bilder folder. To make this example work, you need to append the directory to the file name so that you have the complete path to the image.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

def read_image():
    'reading the images'
    folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"Bilder")
    for i in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(folder + '/' + i)
        print(img.shape)


read_image()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives me the same mistake